# Criar um objeto a partir de outra classe

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Possuo a classe `Endereco` e a classe `Cliente`, construi 2 construtores para a `Cliente`, e em um deles é pra ser inserido o nome do cliente e um objeto do tipo `Endereco`, o que funciona perfeitamente, mas no outro construtor é pra ser inserido o nome do `Cliente` e criar um objeto do tipo `Endereco` junto, o problema é que após digitar os dados do `Endereco`, dou inspect e `Endereco` é considerado **null**.

Parte essencial(2 construtores) da classe Endereco:

```
public class Endereco{
    private String logradouro;
    private String numero;
    private String complemento;
    private String telefone;
    private String celular;
    private String email;

    public Endereco(String log, String num, String comp, String tel, String cel, String mail){
        logradouro = log;
        numero = num;
        complemento = comp;
        telefone = tel;
        celular = cel;
        email = mail;
    }    
    public Endereco(){
        Teclado t = new Teclado();
        logradouro = t.leString("Informe o logradouro: ");
        numero = t.leString("Informe o numero: ");
        complemento = t.leString("Informe o complemento: ");
        telefone = t.leString("Informe o telefone: ");
        celular = t.leString("Informe o celular: ");
        email = t.leString("Informe o e-mail: ");
    }
}
```

Parte essencial da classe Cliente:

```
public class Cliente{

    private String nome;
    private Endereco endereco;
    private int pontos;

    public Cliente(String nm, Endereco ed){
        nome = nm;
        endereco = ed;
        pontos = 0;
    }
    public Cliente(String nm){
        nome = nm;
        Endereco e = new Endereco();
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloque em `Endereco e`, troque por `this.endereco` = `new Endereco()`, porque se ta criando um outro `objeto` da da `classe` **Endereco**, que não condiz com o private criado dentro da classe Cliente ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em vez disso:

```
Endereco e = new Endereco();
```

Faça isso

```
this.endereco = new Endereco();
```

Você esqueceu de atribuir a nova instância ao atributo da classe.

Comment: valeu meu, um erro bobo e simples mesmo mas que eu nunca iria me ligar hahaha

Answer (score 3):

Julgo que o problema está na forma como você declara o Endereço no segundo construtor você deve usar a variável `privada endereco` e não declarar outra.

```
private String nome;
private Endereco endereco;
private int pontos;

public Cliente(String nm, Endereco ed){
    nome = nm;
    endereco = ed;
    pontos = 0;
}
public Cliente(String nm){
    nome = nm;
    endereco = new Endereco(); // use a variável privada
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta Instanciar o objeto dando um new no Endereço dentro co construtor sem parâmetro, ele ficou nulo pois o mesmo não foi instanciado

```
this.endereco = new  Endereco();
```